# Convert Angularfire2/Firestore observable to promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how to convert Angularfire2/Firestore observable to promise?
I have tried as shown below. But it doesn't work and no errors too.

*.ts*

```
  this.categories$ = this.categoryProvider.getAllContactCategories().valueChanges();
   const defaultCategories = await this.categories$.map((response) => response).toPromise();//after this line it won't execute
   await Promise.all(defaultCategories.map(async (c: Category) => {
   await this.categoryProvider.createCategory(c.name, project.id);
      }));
```

*provider.ts*

```
  getAllContactCategories(): AngularFirestoreCollection<Category> {
    return this.fireStore.collection(`contactCategories`);
  }
```

Comment: but y would you want to do that. There are diiferent ways of doing things asyncronously in typescript. Why do u need `async await` only?

Comment: Yes, I need to use `async/await` pattern here since this is just a small part of the method. I have used that pattern throughout that method. So that is the reason for that. @NamanKheterpal

Comment: I cant help you to answer your question, but I can only suggest this is very bad practice of using so many `await`. There are reasons why angular prefer `observable` over `promises`. I can help you to achieve same result using observable only though.

Comment: Yes, there are use cases where we need to use promises over observable. I have found the solution. Thanks for your feedback :) @NamanKheterpal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done it like so: Cheers :)

***Note:*** This is just for updating few default records of the `master table`. No more than that :)

```
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.categories$ = this.categoryProvider.getAllContactCategories().valueChanges();
const defaultCategories = await this.categories$.map(categories => {
     categories.forEach(async (c) => {
         await this.categoryProvider.createCategory(c.name, project.id);
      });
   }).pipe(first()).toPromise();
```

Comment: using `async/await` in `forEach` like seriously? Is this only thing you have.

Comment: Yes, This is more than enough for my use case @NamanKheterpal

Comment: This is just for updating few records of the `master table`. No more than that. @NamanKheterpal

Comment: there is a function of rxJs naming `.flatMap` It would help you do the same thing with observable. :D

Comment: I cannot use observable here. I have mentioned the reason earlier @NamanKheterpal